# PostgresSQL aliased subquery returning records that really don't exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have a query that returns 16 records:

```
            SELECT
            * 
            FROM 
                historical
            where event_code = 'EMV0727E'
            and price_level_name = '99'
```

[image]

If I make that an aliased subquery, like so:

```
SELECT 
    ttable.*
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        historical.event_code,
        historical.datestr,
        CASE
            WHEN (historical.price_level_name = '0'::text) THEN '99'::text
            ELSE historical.price_level_name
        END AS price_level_name        
    FROM 
        historical
) ttable
where ttable.event_code = 'EMV0727E'
and ttable.price_level_name = '99'
```

it returns the records I expect, plus a bunch of records that aren't even in the historical table.

[image]

Might any of the Postgres experts out there have any tips for me. I have always assumed the aliased query behaves like a temp table.

Comment: in what regard?

Comment: a table and result set are by nature unsorted, so as long as you don't give an OEDER BY the result can be other sorted  as well

Comment: So the sorting isn't the issue. What's odd to me is that records in result set 2 with the datestr value of '2019-01-02 11:59:00-06' don't even exist in the first result set. So where would a parent query even get those values?

Comment: in the second query you are potentially creating new entires with price_level_name = 99 with this clause ```WHEN (historical.price_level_name = '0'::text) THEN '99'::text```  maybe try temporarily changing that 99 to 88 and rerun the query to see if that fixes the issue.  (note creating new entries with 99 by changing existing non 99 entries to 99)

Comment: Just tried changing to '88'. No difference. But I think you're on to something. If I take out all the case stuff. I get the right result. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: i don't sse what is the correct result, my guess is the it sort the data different and you have a auto limit somewhere

Comment: Try `select * from historical where event_code = 'EMV0727E' and price_level_name in ('0', '99')`. I think you'll find your mystery rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query isn't equal to the one you've used as the subquery. It's easier to spot this if you pull up both what goes into the `case` statement and what comes out: [demo1](https://dbfiddle.uk/0n4YkqTE)

```
select setseed(0.1);
create table historical (event_code text, price_level_name text, datestr timestamptz);
insert into historical 
select ('{EMV0727E,EMV0726D,EMV0725C}'::text[])[1+random()*2],
       ('{0,5,99}'::text[])[1+random()*2],
       '2023-10-24'::date-'1 month'::interval*random()
from generate_series(1,20,1);

SELECT * 
FROM historical
where event_code = 'EMV0727E'
and price_level_name = '99'
```

| event_code | price_level_name | datestr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EMV0727E | 99 | 2023-10-14 08:18:27.2736+00 |

```
SELECT  ttable.*
FROM ( 
    SELECT  historical.event_code,
            historical.datestr,
            historical.price_level_name AS price_level_name,
            CASE WHEN (historical.price_level_name = '0'::text) 
                 THEN '99'::text
                 ELSE historical.price_level_name
            END AS new_price_level_name
    FROM historical ) ttable
where ttable.event_code = 'EMV0727E'
and ttable.new_price_level_name = '99'
```

| event_code | datestr | price_level_name | new_price_level_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EMV0727E | 2023-10-14 08:18:27.2736+00 | 99 | 99 |
| EMV0727E | 2023-10-01 04:04:59.4912+00 | 0 | 99 |

---

As long as the query doesn't rely on a [volatile routine](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html) or the underlying tables don't mutate between tests (→[MVCC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/mvcc.html)), it doesn't matter whether you put the query in a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html), a [subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-SUBQUERIES), a [view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html), a table/set-returning [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS); row order might be different but the result set is guaranteed to stay consistent. With matching `order by`, identical.

In fact, with [query rewrite rule system](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules.html), [JIT inlining](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/jit-reason.html#JIT-INLINING) and the option to disable [CTE materialization](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-CTE-MATERIALIZATION) (which is what I think you had in mind referring to a "temp table" behaviour), all of these can easily end up being rewritten the exact same way, merged directly into your query.

You can test this warranty - code below should work with your real table. [Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/v0KRYHKw):

```sql
create view v_historical as 
  SELECT * FROM historical
  where event_code = 'EMV0727E'
  and price_level_name = '99' 
  order by event_code,price_level_name,datestr;
create function f_historical() returns setof historical language sql as $f$
  SELECT * FROM historical
  where event_code = 'EMV0727E'
  and price_level_name = '99' 
  order by event_code,price_level_name,datestr $f$;
```

```sql
with cte as (
  SELECT * FROM historical
  where event_code = 'EMV0727E'
  and price_level_name = '99' 
  order by event_code,price_level_name,datestr)
select 'direct FROM' as type,
       md5(string_agg(concat(frm.event_code::text, 
                             frm.price_level_name, 
                             frm.datestr::text)
                      ,'' order by frm.event_code,
                                   frm.price_level_name,
                                   frm.datestr)) as result_checksum
from historical as frm
where frm.event_code = 'EMV0727E'
and frm.price_level_name = '99' 
union all select 'scalar subquery',
                 md5((select string_agg(concat(ssbq.event_code::text, ssbq.price_level_name, ssbq.datestr::text)
                                        ,'' order by ssbq.event_code, ssbq.price_level_name, ssbq.datestr)
                      from historical as ssbq where ssbq.event_code = 'EMV0727E'
                      and ssbq.price_level_name = '99'))
union all select 'view',
                 md5(string_agg(concat(vw.event_code::text, vw.price_level_name, vw.datestr::text),''))
from v_historical as vw
union all select 'subquery', 
                 md5(string_agg(concat(sbq.event_code::text, sbq.price_level_name, sbq.datestr::text),''))
from ( SELECT * FROM historical where event_code = 'EMV0727E' and price_level_name = '99' order by event_code,price_level_name,datestr) 
     as sbq
union all select 'cte',
                 md5(string_agg(concat(cte.event_code::text, cte.price_level_name, cte.datestr::text),''))
from cte
union all select 'function',
                 md5(string_agg(concat(func.event_code::text, func.price_level_name, func.datestr::text),''))
from f_historical() as func;
```

| type | result_checksum |
| --- | --- |
| scalar subquery | 99fe232d18a97adaf6d6bacdf063da1e |
| direct FROM | 99fe232d18a97adaf6d6bacdf063da1e |
| view | 99fe232d18a97adaf6d6bacdf063da1e |
| subquery | 99fe232d18a97adaf6d6bacdf063da1e |
| cte | 99fe232d18a97adaf6d6bacdf063da1e |
| function | 99fe232d18a97adaf6d6bacdf063da1e |

Comment: Thank you. This is great. Much appreciated.